# Equivalent in C# of Python's "struct.pack/unpack"?

Tags: c#, byte, converters

I am a seasoned Python developer and have come to love a lot of its conveniences. I have actually known C# for some time but recently have gotten into some more advanced coding.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to "parse" a byte array in C# into a set of (differently sized) items.

Imagine we have this:

Python:

```
import struct
byteArray = "\xFF\xFF\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x01\x00\x00\x00"
numbers = struct.unpack("<LHL",byteArray)
print numbers[0] # 65535
print numbers[1] # 255
print numbers[2] # 1

newNumbers = [0, 255, 1023]
byteArray = struct.pack("<HHL",newNumbers)
print byteArray # '\x00\x00\xFF\x00\xFF\x03\x00\x00'
```

I want to achieve the same effect in C#, without resorting to huge, messy amounts of code like this:

C#:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] temp;

int[] values = new int[3];

temp = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, temp, 0, 4);
values[0] = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp);

temp = new byte[2];
Array.Copy(byteArray, 4, temp, 0, 2);
values[1] = BitConverter.ToInt16(temp);

temp = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(byteArray, 8, temp, 0, 4);
values[2] = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp);

// Now values contains an array of integer values.
// It would be OK to assume a common maximum (e.g. Int64) and just cast up to that,
// but we still have to consider the size of the source bytes.

// Now the other way.
int[] values = new int[] { 0, 255, 1023 };
byteArray = new byte[8];

temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(values[0]);
Array.Copy(temp,2,byteArray,0,2);

temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(values[1]);
Array.Copy(temp,2,byteArray,2,2);

temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(values[2]);
Array.Copy(temp,0,byteArray,4,4);
```

Obviously the C# code I have is *very* specific and not in any way truly reusable.

Advice?

Comment: I'm curious about the performance of the various techniques as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ended up writing my own class to handle this. It's pretty complex, but it does seem to work. It's also incomplete, but it works for what I need at this point. Feel free to use it, and if there's any good improvements, please let me know.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

// This is a crude implementation of a format string based struct converter for C#.
// This is probably not the best implementation, the fastest implementation, the most bug-proof implementation, or even the most functional implementation.
// It's provided as-is for free. Enjoy.

public class StructConverter
{
    // We use this function to provide an easier way to type-agnostically call the GetBytes method of the BitConverter class.
    // This means we can have much cleaner code below.
    private static byte[] TypeAgnosticGetBytes(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return BitConverter.GetBytes((int)o);
        if (o is uint) return BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)o);
        if (o is long) return BitConverter.GetBytes((long)o);
        if (o is ulong) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)o);
        if (o is short) return BitConverter.GetBytes((short)o);
        if (o is ushort) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)o);
        if (o is byte || o is sbyte) return new byte[] { (byte)o };
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    private static string GetFormatSpecifierFor(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return "i";
        if (o is uint) return "I";
        if (o is long) return "q";
        if (o is ulong) return "Q";
        if (o is short) return "h";
        if (o is ushort) return "H";
        if (o is byte) return "B";
        if (o is sbyte) return "b";
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a byte array into an array of objects based on Python's "struct.unpack" protocol.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fmt">A "struct.pack"-compatible format string</param>
    /// <param name="bytes">An array of bytes to convert to objects</param>
    /// <returns>Array of objects.</returns>
    /// <remarks>You are responsible for casting the objects in the array back to their proper types.</remarks>
    public static object[] Unpack(string fmt, byte[] bytes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Format string is length {0}, {1} bytes provided.", fmt.Length, bytes.Length);

        // First we parse the format string to make sure it's proper.
        if (fmt.Length < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Format string cannot be empty.");

        bool endianFlip = false;
        if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == "<")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: little endian");
            // Little endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == false) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }
        else if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == ">")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: big endian");
            // Big endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }

        // Now, we find out how long the byte array needs to be
        int totalByteLength = 0;
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("  Format character found: {0}", c);
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    totalByteLength += 8;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'I':
                    totalByteLength += 4;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                case 'H':
                    totalByteLength += 2;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                case 'x':
                    totalByteLength += 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid character found in format string.");
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Endianness will {0}be flipped.", (object) (endianFlip == true ? "" : "NOT "));
        Debug.WriteLine("The byte array is expected to be {0} bytes long.", totalByteLength);

        // Test the byte array length to see if it contains as many bytes as is needed for the string.
        if (bytes.Length != totalByteLength) throw new ArgumentException("The number of bytes provided does not match the total length of the format string.");

        // Ok, we can go ahead and start parsing bytes!
        int byteArrayPosition = 0;
        List<object> outputList = new List<object>();
        byte[] buf;

        Debug.WriteLine("Processing byte array...");
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(long)BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes,byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition+=8;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ulong)BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes,byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition+=8;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    outputList.Add((object)(int)BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition+=4;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    outputList.Add((object)(uint)BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition+=4;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsignedsigned 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    outputList.Add((object)(short)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ushort)BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes,byteArrayPosition,buf,0,1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(sbyte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed byte");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, byteArrayPosition, buf, 0, 1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(byte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned byte");
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Ignoring a byte");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("You should not be here.");
            }
        }
        return outputList.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an array of objects to a byte array, along with a string that can be used with Unpack.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">An object array of items to convert</param>
    /// <param name="LittleEndian">Set to False if you want to use big endian output.</param>
    /// <param name="NeededFormatStringToRecover">Variable to place an 'Unpack'-compatible format string into.</param>
    /// <returns>A Byte array containing the objects provided in binary format.</returns>
    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items, bool LittleEndian, out string NeededFormatStringToRecover)
    {

        // make a byte list to hold the bytes of output
        List<byte> outputBytes = new List<byte>();

        // should we be flipping bits for proper endinanness?
        bool endianFlip = (LittleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);

        // start working on the output string
        string outString = (LittleEndian == false ? ">" : "<");

        // convert each item in the objects to the representative bytes
        foreach (object o in items)
        {
            byte[] theseBytes = TypeAgnosticGetBytes(o);
            if (endianFlip == true) theseBytes = (byte[])theseBytes.Reverse();
            outString += GetFormatSpecifierFor(o);
            outputBytes.AddRange(theseBytes);
        }

        NeededFormatStringToRecover = outString;

        return outputBytes.ToArray();

    }

    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items)
    {
        string dummy = "";
        return Pack(items, true, out dummy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome translation. Just a point to consider the cases i and I in the first loop should be part of the cases l and L in the second loop

Comment: Can you provide an example how to use this class...?
I'm asking because Python Pack is declared as:
struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)
Return a string containing the values v1, v2, ... packed according to the given format. The arguments must match the values required by the format exactly.
if I call your Pack as StructConverter.Pack(new object[] { "<l", 34 }) which is the equivalent of struct.pack('<l', 34) of course I get:
 throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");

Comment: @Jimi , you don't put format into his Pack method. That's pretty huge difference from Python's implementation, but it is what it is. I've posted my version which in behaviour is much closer to Python's code

Answer (score 3):

.NET (and thus, C#) has the `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` methods.

You can abuse these to cast raw memory to a `struct` like you would in C, not that I'd recommend doing it this way (as it isn't exactly portable). You also need to get your `Byte[]` array buffer into the native heap in order to perform the operation on it:

```cs
public static T FromBuffer<T>( Byte[] buffer )
    where T : struct, new()
{
    T temp = new T();
    Int32  size = Marshal.SizeOf( temp );
    IntPtr ptr  = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( size );
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy( buffer, 0, ptr, size );

        T ret = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure( ptr, temp.GetType() );

        return ret;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal( ptr );
    }  
}
```

Comment: If you pin the buffer using `fixed (byte* b = buffer)`, you can avoid the additional heap allocation and can simply return the marshalled object directly (and not have to worry about cleanup either).

Answer (score 3):

BinaryWriter and BinaryReader will send arbitrary items to a byte array or read arbitrary items from a byte array

```
var str = new MemoryStream();
var bw = new BinaryWriter(str);
bw.Write(42);
bw.Write("hello");
...
var bytes = str.ToArray();
```

Comment: `BinaryReader|Writer` does not support writing/reading structs, only primitives, strings and byte arrays.

Comment: indeed - but is does exactly what he wants and is the c# logical equivalent of the pack/unpack

Comment: BinaryWriter is big endian only, so it can't be used for network.

Comment: @VelizarHristov: You might have that backwards.  Network order is big endian by definition.

Comment: You can always use `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` to convert bytes to big endian. `BinaryWriter` will write in machine order which is usually little endian.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to suggest my solution, I'd propose this one I wrote, it performs in a closer manner to what Python does than other solutions.
Of course it's much easier to implement with Python's dynamic typing.

It misses those floating point formats (but I guess they could be easily added?).

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestApp;

public static class StructPacker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Packs the values according to the provided format
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="format">Format matching Python's struct.pack: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html</param>
    /// <param name="values">Values to pack</param>
    /// <returns>Byte array containing packed values</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when values array doesn't have enough entries to match the format</exception>
    public static byte[] Pack(string format, params object[] values)
    {
        var builder = new BinaryArrayBuilder();
        var littleEndian = true;
        var valueCtr = 0;
        foreach (var ch in format)
        {
            if (ch == '<')
            {
                littleEndian = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '>')
            {
                littleEndian = false;
            }
            else if (ch == 'x')
            {
                builder.AppendByte(0x00);
            }
            else
            {
                if (valueCtr >= values.Length)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Provided too little values for given format string");

                var (formatType, _) = GetFormatType(ch);
                var value = Convert.ChangeType(values[valueCtr], formatType);
                var bytes = TypeAgnosticGetBytes(value);
                var endianFlip = littleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
                if (endianFlip)
                    bytes = (byte[])bytes.Reverse();

                builder.AppendBytes(bytes);

                valueCtr++;
            }
        }

        return builder.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unpacks data from byte array to tuple according to format provided
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Tuple type to return values in</typeparam>
    /// <param name="data">Bytes that should contain your values</param>
    /// <returns>Tuple containing unpacked values</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when values array doesn't have enough entries to match the format</exception>
    public static T Unpack<T>(string format, byte[] data)
        where T : ITuple
    {
        List<object> resultingValues = new List<object>();
        var littleEndian = true;
        var valueCtr = 0;
        var dataIx = 0;
        var tupleType = typeof(T);
        foreach(var ch in format)
        {
            if (ch == '<')
            {
                littleEndian = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '>')
            {
                littleEndian = false;
            }
            else if (ch == 'x')
            {
                dataIx++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (valueCtr >= tupleType.GenericTypeArguments.Length)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Provided too little tuple arguments for given format string");

                var (formatType, formatSize) = GetFormatType(ch);

                var valueBytes = data[dataIx..(dataIx + formatSize)];
                var endianFlip = littleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
                if (endianFlip)
                    valueBytes = (byte[])valueBytes.Reverse();

                var value = TypeAgnosticGetValue(formatType, valueBytes);

                var genericType = tupleType.GenericTypeArguments[valueCtr];
                if (genericType == typeof(bool))
                    resultingValues.Add(value);
                else
                    resultingValues.Add(Convert.ChangeType(value, genericType));

                valueCtr++;
                dataIx += formatSize;
            }
        }

        if (resultingValues.Count != tupleType.GenericTypeArguments.Length)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Mismatch between generic argument count and pack format");

        var constructor = tupleType.GetConstructor(tupleType.GenericTypeArguments);
        return (T)constructor!.Invoke(resultingValues.ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to unpack single value from byte array. Shorthand to not have to declare and deconstruct tuple in your code
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">Type of value you need</typeparam>
    /// <param name="data">Bytes that should contain your values</param>
    /// <returns>Value unpacked from data</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when values array doesn't have enough entries to match the format</exception>
    public static TValue UnpackSingle<TValue>(string format, byte[] data)
    {
        var templateTuple = new ValueTuple<TValue>(default!);
        var unpackResult =  Unpack(templateTuple, format, data);
        return unpackResult.Item1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Workaround for language limitations XD Couldn't call Unpack<(T value)>(format, data) in UnpackSingle
    /// </summary>
    private static T Unpack<T>(T _, string format, byte[] data)
        where T : ITuple
    {
        return Unpack<T>(format, data);
    }

    private static (Type type, int size) GetFormatType(char formatChar)
    {
        return formatChar switch
        {
            'i' => (typeof(int), sizeof(int)),
            'I' => (typeof(uint), sizeof(uint)),
            'q' => (typeof(long), sizeof(long)),
            'Q' => (typeof(ulong), sizeof(ulong)),
            'h' => (typeof(short), sizeof(short)),
            'H' => (typeof(ushort), sizeof(ushort)),
            'b' => (typeof(sbyte), sizeof(sbyte)),
            'B' => (typeof(byte), sizeof(byte)),
            '?' => (typeof(bool), 1),
            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown format char"),
        };
    }

    // We use this function to provide an easier way to type-agnostically call the GetBytes method of the BitConverter class.
    // This means we can have much cleaner code below.
    private static byte[] TypeAgnosticGetBytes(object o)
    {
        if (o is bool b) return b ? new byte[] { 0x01 } : new byte[] { 0x00 };
        if (o is int x) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
        if (o is uint x2) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x2);
        if (o is long x3) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x3);
        if (o is ulong x4) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x4);
        if (o is short x5) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x5);
        if (o is ushort x6) return BitConverter.GetBytes(x6);
        if (o is byte || o is sbyte) return new byte[] { (byte)o };
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    private static object TypeAgnosticGetValue(Type type, byte[] data)
    {
        if (type == typeof(bool)) return data[0] > 0;
        if (type == typeof(int)) return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(uint)) return BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(long)) return BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(ulong)) return BitConverter.ToUInt64(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(short)) return BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(ushort)) return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 0);
        if (type == typeof(byte)) return data[0];
        if (type == typeof(sbyte)) return (sbyte)data[0];
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }
}
```

You will also need another class I'm using (or change it to use MemoryStream directly), `BinaryArrayBuilder`, which idea is to kind of mimic StringBuilder by wrapping MemoryStream so it can be easily used and yet more efficient than `List<byte>`

```
namespace TestApp;

public class BinaryArrayBuilder
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _innerStream;

    public BinaryArrayBuilder()
    {
        _innerStream = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public BinaryArrayBuilder(byte[] initialBuffer)
    {
        _innerStream = new MemoryStream(initialBuffer);
    }

    public void AppendByte(byte value)
    {
        _innerStream.WriteByte(value);
    }

    public void AppendBytes(byte[] values)
    {
        _innerStream.Write(values);
    }

    public void AppendValues(string format, params object[] values)
    {
        AppendBytes(StructPacker.Pack(format, values));
    }

    public byte[] ToArray() => _innerStream.ToArray();
}
```

You use it pretty much as close to Python as I could get with static typed C#:

```
StructPacker.Pack("<BBi", 0x83, 123, 12345678);
var (pid, dataLength) = StructPacker.Unpack<(int, byte)>(">IB", readBytes);
var anotherUnpack = StructPacker.Unpack<(int pid, byte length)>(">IB", readBytes);
Console.WriteLine($"PID: {anotherUnpack.pid}, Len: {anotherUnpack.length}");
var singleInt = StructPacker.Unpack<int>("<i", data);
```

BTW, I'm using .NET 7 and latest language features, so if it doesn't compile directly for you, you might need a little adjustments ;)

It's just a pity that such feature is not builtin into .NET with BitConverter class.

Answer (score -1):

example like this,python:struct.pack("H", 739),"H" is for ushort,in c#: BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)739); python:struct.unpack("H"),c#：BitConverter.ToUInt16()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).