# Python to C#: how to format data for sockets?

Tags: c#, python, sockets, formatting

I am translating a python communication library into C#, and am having trouble interpreting how the string gets formatted before being sent over tcp.

The relevant portion of the code is as follows:

```
struct.pack(
            '!HHBH'+str(var_name_len)+'s',
            self.msg_id,
            req_len,
            flag,
            var_name_len,
            self.varname
)
```

Then it gets sent with: sendall()

I have looked at the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) but am still drawing a blank regarding the first line: '!HHBH'+str(var_name_len)+'s', I understand this is where the formatting is set, but what it is being formatted to is beyond me.

The python code that I am translating can be found at the following link:
https://github.com/linuxsand/py_openshowvar/blob/master/py_openshowvar.py

Any python and C# vigilantes out there that can help me build this bridge?

Edit: Based on jas' answer, I have written the following c# struct:

```
public struct messageFormat
    {
        ushort messageId;
        ushort reqLength;
        char functionType;
        ushort varLengthHex;
        string varname; 
    ...
```

Once I populate it, I will need to send it over TCP. I have an open socket, but need to convert to to a byte[] I assume so I can use socket.send(byte[])?

Thanks

Comment: There's always [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)!

Comment: This may be helpful [equivalent-in-c-sharp-of-pythons-struct-pack-unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225303/equivalent-in-c-sharp-of-pythons-struct-pack-unpack)

Answer (score 0):

What's being formatted are the five arguments following the format string. Each argument has a corresponding element in the format string.

For the sake of the explanation, let's assume that `var_name_len` has the value 12 (presumably because `var_name` is a string of length 12 in this hypothetical case).

So the format string will be

```
!HHBH12s
```

Breaking that down according to the docs:

```
!    Big-ending byte ordering will be used
H    self.msg_id will be packed as a two-byte unsigned short
H    req_len will be packed as above
B    flag will be packed as a one-byte unsigned char
H    var_name_len will be packed as a two-byte unsigned short
12s  self.varname will be packed as a 12-byte string
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, it totally makes sense now. Any leads into specifying the character formatting and byte ordering using C# Sockets? Sorry for all the questions but I am new to coding in low level applications.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm only useful for the Python end of this question, no experience with C#.  Sorry I can't help with the rest, but I'm sure someone will know.