# C# equivalent of struct.unpack('!d', x.decode('hex'))[0]

Tags: c#, python

I am reading a data which is stored binaries. In python I can decode the file easily.

input `x` is `"bfdle8074442d180"`

```
data = struct.unpack('!d', x.decode('hex'))[0]
```

The result is `-0.684573777506`

I would like to do the same decoding in **C#**, do we have anything similar?
someone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent in C# of Python's "struct.pack/unpack"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225303/equivalent-in-c-sharp-of-pythons-struct-pack-unpack)

Comment: Uhm, yes. We have.

Comment: do u  know how to do that? :)