# Python's pack/unpack in .Net

Tags: python, c#, byte, converters

Is there any function equivalent to Python's struct.pack and struck.unpack in C# that allows me to pack and unpack values like this?

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what these methods actually do, on what data structure or type, example input an output perhaps. How you intend to use it, what is not working for you now, what problems you are having ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225303/equivalent-in-c-sharp-of-pythons-struct-pack-unpack

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code but rather paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You'll have to do it manually with a `BinaryWriter`, or a `MemoryStream` with `BitConverter` or the new `BinaryPrimitives` plus a `Span<>` supported probably by a `byte[]` (but it is more complex... You have to know the resulting width of the buffer before you begin to write, while the `MemoryStream` is auto-enlarging).

It gets even worse: with .NET using a multi-type array (an array where every element can be of any type) like the one returned by `unpack` is a little frowned upon, and it is low performance. You have to use a `object[]`, so you'll box every element.

Now... Manually "serializing" to binary is quite easy (even if much longer than Python):

```
byte command_type = 1;
byte command_class = 5;
byte command_code = 0x14;
int arg0 = 0;
int arg1 = 0;

// We know the message plus the checksum has length 12
var packedMessage2 = new byte[12];

// We use the new Span feature
var span = new Span<byte>(packedMessage2);

// We can directly set the single bytes
span[0] = command_type;
span[1] = command_class;
span[2] = command_code;

// The pack is <, so little endian. Note the use of Slice: first the position (3 or 7), then the length of the data (4 for int)
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(3, 4), arg0);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(7, 4), arg1);

// The checksum
// The sum is modulo 255, because it is a single byte.
// the unchecked is normally useless because it is standard in C#, but we write it to make it clear
var sum = unchecked((byte)packedMessage2.Take(11).Sum(x => x));

// We set the sum
span[11] = sum;

// Without checksum
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(packedMessage2.Take(11).Select(x => $@"\x{x:x2}")));

// With checksum
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(packedMessage2.Select(x => $@"\x{x:x2}")));
```

Comment: Bro! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) Library .

There's an unpack method similar to what you've posted in the image

```
 struct.pack(format, v1, v2, ...)

    Return a bytes object containing the values v1, v2, … packed according to the format string format. The arguments must match the values required by the format exactly
```